# How to append constantly changing stderr to a file or stdout

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I might not have been able to phrase my search properly but I could not find any way to collect all values of `stderr/stdout` in cases where it is overwritten every second of the execution.

It's not a problem with commands like `top` because it writes a fresh page to `stdout` for per-second-statistics but in certain cases like `curl` where progress is shown in `stderr` and it is overwritten every second, I could not find a way to collect all the per-second values of the `stderr`, which I need for protocol analysis.

To add further detail:

```
$ curl -o /dev/null --trace-ascii trace --trace-time    http://cachefly.cachefly.net/10mb.test
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0 10.0M    0 65057    0     0  43039      0  0:04:03  0:00:01  0:04:02 43027^C

$ curl -o /dev/null --trace-ascii trace --trace-time http://cachefly.cachefly.net/10mb.test
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
13 10.0M   13 1376k    0     0   425k      0  0:00:24  0:00:03  0:00:21  425k^C
```

As you can see, `stderr` is being displayed on `stdout` but is overwritten every second. Even if I append it to a file, the file only contains the last value before the command was terminated whereas I want the file to contain a list of all per-second values.
I've read every line of `man curl` to see if any such thing is possible but maybe that's not where I should be looking. Any help/redirection would be appreciated!

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output contains the `$'\r'` character which moves the cursor back to the beginning of line. Just replace it with newlines in the file and you'll see all the lines.

```
sed -i~ 's/\r/\n/g' input
```

`sed` needs to read the whole "line" to produce output, so if you don't want to wait till the end, switch to Perl:

```
curl -o /dev/null --trace-ascii trace --trace-time http://cachefly.cachefly.net/10mb.test 2>&1 \
    | perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/="\r"}s/\r/\n/'
```

Comment: so you need to write some continuous command doing this replacement during the execution of `curl`?

Comment: If you want to filter the output on the fly, just plug `sed` to the pipeline: `curl ... 2>&1 | sed 's/\r/\n/g'`.

Comment: Nice! Probably better to say `sed 's/\r/\n/g'` so every lines appears in a different line, not everything together.

Comment: `curl -o /dev/null --trace-ascii trace --trace-time http://cachefly.cachefly.net/10mb.test 2>&1 | sed 's/\r//g'` gives nothing. Also tried replacing it with newline and using different quoting styles since I'm an amateur but nothing worked.

Comment: @Donbhupi: Weird. It works for me (note the `\n` for nicer output). You have to wait till the end as sed needs the end of line to process the input.

Comment: thanks, appended this usage of `\r` to my brain's database and that `sed` needs EOF to terminate. And the use of `perl` does make this answer a pearl!

Comment: @choroba If I use `cut` or `awk` for certain columns of the output, I have to wait again for EOF. I know it's off-topic here but I guess you'd already know how to include a cut-like feature in your perl one-liner.

Comment: @Donbhupi: It's better to start a new question.